# Webcam recognised by cheese but not by Skype

Tags: webcam

I recently connected an old Microsoft Webcam to my Ubuntu desktop.  Whilst the camera works fine with Cheese, it isn't recognised by Skype/Zoom.  Is there something I am missing???

I should have mentioned that strangely the audio part of Skype appears to be recognising the USB camera but the video/camera part does not.

Answer (score -1):

I've had an issue like that before and i had to change the in-app settings on Skype then restart the app to fix it
-edit-

1. Open the Skype app
2. Ctrl+comma to open up the settings section
3. Go to Audio & Video
4. Activate your camera

Comment: Be more specific about changes you've done.

Comment: Thank you for the additional comments. I tried that but the camera is not available to choose.

Comment: @ABingham Oh sorry then I don’t have any other tips

Comment: Cheers bud. Thanks for trying.